# Transformation of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j \left(\frac{1}{j^t} - \frac{1}{(j+1)^t}\right)$$ for $t>0$.

Can I rewrite that as:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^t} $$

Comment: It looks like the answer is yes, as the first sum is a partial-summation version of the second sum.

Comment: @GregMartin: How can see that in detail?

Comment: See, [for instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts); here you have $b_j=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting
$$\sum_{j=1}^{N} j \left(\frac{1}{j^t} - \frac{1}{(j+1)^t}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{N} \left(\frac{1}{j^{t-1}} - \frac{(j+1)-1}{(j+1)^t}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{N} \left(\frac{1}{j^{t-1}} - \frac{1}{(j+1)^{t-1}}+\frac{1}{(j+1)^t}\right)=1-\frac{1}{(N+1)^{t-1}}+\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{(j+1)^t}$$
and letting $N\to\infty$,
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j \left(\frac{1}{j^t} - \frac{1}{(j+1)^t}\right)=1+\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(j+1)^t}.$$